# I want to add multiple select queries in stored procedure by using flag - how will I do this?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[UserManagement]
    @flag int
AS
BEGIN
    IF @flag = 1
    BEGIN
        SELECT 
            Formatid, Formatdetail, dispformat  
        FROM
            loy_Formatdetail with (nolock)
        WHERE 
            isactive = '1' 
            AND memberstatus = 'Member' 
        ORDER BY 
            FormatDetail
    END
END
```

Comment: i want to add more select queries in this by attaching flag how will i do please help..

Comment: Sounds like a horribly bad design idea..... why pack x unrelated queries into a single stored procedure, which then returns different "shapes" of responses depending on which query has been executed?? You're just **asking** for trouble and pain in the long run - **don't do it!** - if you have x unrelated queries - you should package those up into x unrelateted stored procedures - one for each query .....

Comment: No, they are related to each other and have same parameters... actully i want to use them for my 4dropdown in asp.net according to that i have put filters the  data which is available will be shown in gridview

Comment: What do you mean by "more select queries in this by attaching flag"? You can consider writing IF-else blocks for every flag values.

Comment: can you please show me any example so that i can do